# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException in Amazon EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am trying to run WordCount program in Amazon EMR but I got the error saying :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory s3://mywordcountbuckett/run0 already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

[image]

I have tried to Google the solution online and came across the solution which advised like this

```
 The work around this is to not output to the top level of your bucket. So for instance "s3n://test.output/run0".
```

I have tried but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Does the "directory" exists on s3?

If so you have to delete it prior to running the hadoop job again.

You can check using s3cmd or the aws cli tools

```
s3cmd ls s3://mywordcountbuckett/run0/

aws s3 ls s3://mywordcountbuckett/run0/
```

To delete the data (This will delete all data under s3://mywordcountbuckett/run0/)

```
s3cmd del -r s3://mywordcountbuckett/run0/

aws s3 rm s3://mywordcountbuckett/run0/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify parameters as following with output not at the top level:

wordcount s3://youremrinput/ s3://youremrout/out/

Make sure output directory does not exist